# JAXB - SAXParseException Cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have a problem trying to validate an object with a given xsd.
The classes has been generated from the xsd.

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory
                .newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(getClass().getResource("/xsd/test.xsd"));
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(aClass);
Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
u.setSchema(schema);
Object anObject = u.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(
                MESSAGE)), aClass);
```

Here is the exception message

[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ACCESREFUSE'.]

Here is the XSD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="./include/CJCommon.xsd"/>
 <xs:element name="ACCESREFUSE">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
    <!-- Entete -->
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="IDOper"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="DateEvt"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="IDEvt"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="IDJoueur"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="HashJoueur"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="IDSession"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="IPJoueur"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="IDCoffre"/>
    <!-- Corps -->
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="TypAg"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CauseRefus" type="string-1024"/>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TypeRefus">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="string-1024">
          <xs:enumeration value="DelaiIdentite"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="RejetIdentite"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="Interdit"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="AutoInterdit"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="OpVerrouille"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="Verrouille"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="Cloture"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="Autre"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The element ACCESREFUSE is the root of the xml.

XML :

```
 <ACCESREFUSE>
      <dateEvt>Tue Oct 15 11:45:48 CEST 2013</dateEvt>
      <hashJoueur>0000000000000000000000000000000000000000</hashJoueur>
      <typAg>JC</typAg>
      <causeRefus>Interdit</causeRefus>
      <typeRefus>Interdiction Temporaire</typeRefus>
      <idjoueur>81.252.190.129</idjoueur>
      <idoper>002</idoper>
      <idsession>301090</idsession>
      <idevt>0</idevt>
      <ipjoueur/>
      <idcoffre/>
 </ACCESREFUSE>
```

Any idea ?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try modify your schema to:

```
<xs:element name="ACCESREFUSE">
<xs:complexType name="ACCESREFUSE">
...
</xs:schema>
```

**EDIT:**
 I think you have problem with load XSD. Could you change this code for test purpose:

```
InputStream xmlStream = ...
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(xmlStream);
```

Please try it!

**EDIT2:** I tried parse `ACCESREFUSE` class with your `XSD`. I don't know your `./include/CJCommon.xsd` schema, so I omitted. Here is my code:

```
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory
                .newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        File file = new File("test.xml");
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(file);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ACCESREFUSE.class);
    Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
    u.setSchema(schema);
    Object anObject = u.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(
            getMessage())), ACCESREFUSE.class);
```

The my ACCESREFUSE.class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ACCESREFUSE")
public class ACCESREFUSE {

    protected String v1;
    protected String v2;
    protected String v3;
    protected String v4;
    protected String v5;
    protected String v6;
    protected String v7;
        protected String v8;
    protected String v9;
    protected String CauseRefus;
    protected TypeRefus typeRefus;

     public enum TypeRefus{
         DelaiIdentite, RejetIdentite, Interdit, AutoInterdit, OpVerrouille, Verrouille, Cloture, Autre;
    }
```

The message:

```
private static String getMessage() {

        return "<ACCESREFUSE>"
                + "<v1>Tue Oct 15 11:45:48 CEST 2013</v1>"
                + "<v2>0000000000000000000000000000000000000000</v2>"
                + "<v3>JC</v3>" + "<v4>Interdit</v4>"   
                + "<v5>81.252.190.129</v5>"
                + "<v6>002</v6>" + "<v7>301090</v7>"
                + "<v8>0</v8>" + "<v9> test </v9>"
                + "<TypeRefus>RejetIdentite</TypeRefus>"

                + "</ACCESREFUSE>";
    }
```

and modified your XSD to simple string elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="ACCESREFUSE">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
    <!-- Entete -->
    <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" name="v1"/>
     ...
```

The program correctly working! :)

So could you check your `./include/CJCommon.xsd`? Are you use xs prefix for `type="xs:string"`?

Comment: Well, this is strange because the validation worked before the error. Only when everything is fine, I have the error with the root element. I have tried with InputStream but the result is the same

Comment: before the exception, the validation worked when the XML wasn't correct. for example it told me to change fields...

Comment: yes it's working thanks. the problem was in the CJCommon :) Thanks for your help !

Comment: @BkSouX so the problem was then one of the included XSD was bad-defined?

Answer (score 0):

May be the namespace issue. you should try import ./include/CJCommon.xsd with proper namespace declaration etc. [link](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx)

Comment: i cannot change the xsd, but i will try.